# TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of null in react

Tags: reactjs

```
  export function UserDisplay(props) {
    const {user, includeFullName} = props
    const nameDisplay = includeFullName === true ? `${user.first_name} ${user.last_name}` : null  

    return <React.Fragment>
          {nameDisplay}
      </React.Fragment>
  }
```

Here when i check the value it comes here like:

```
const name = user.first_name
console.log(name)
```

it prints the log but not work in the code why???

```
 const nameDisplay = includeFullName === true ? `${user.first_name} ${user.last_name}` : null
```

It gets error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of null`

Comment: From the error it's clearly understood that `user` prop is having `null` value. Can you show us how you are using `UserDisplay`?

Comment: It means that the user is assigned to null. I can not see the code which initializing the user, but somewhere the user assignment went not as you expected. Please be aware that the condition of the ```includeFullName``` is true.

Comment: <UserDisplay includeFullName user={tweet.user} />

Comment: In that case `tweet.user` ends up being `null`, which is why you cannot access `first_name` or `last_name`. This is the cause of the error.

Comment: So how to get the value with tweet.user But when i do this                                             const name = user.first_name
console.log(name) I find the required value